# PostgreSQL script that should parse JSON field to a column gives NULL

Tags: json, postgresql

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."id",
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."r_v", 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."transaction_data", 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."entry_datetime", 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."owner_id",
    ("transaction_data" ->> 'SupplierDB') AS "v"
FROM 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction" 
LIMIT 21
```

or

```
SELECT
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."id",
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."r_v", 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."transaction_data", 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."entry_datetime", 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction"."owner_id", 
    ("raw_storage_basetransaction"."transaction_data" ->> 'SupplierDB') AS "v" 
FROM 
    "raw_storage_basetransaction" 
LIMIT 21
```

`v` is always NULL

What did I do wrong?

--UPD--

My fault. I wrote in jsonb field a unicode string instead of json-dict.

Comment: This question is going to be very hard to answer unless you give us some sample data.

Comment: Post the output of `select transaction_data limit 1`

Comment: Has updated post with sample data

Comment: Please check spelling for SupplierDB.